# Как правильно очистить webgl контекст

Tags: webgl, javascript

Всем привет! Есть код на js написанный поверх чистой `webgl` без использования библиотек (за исключением `gl-matrix.js`), который рисует поверхности по точкам, загружаемым из БД. Все отлично  при первоначальном запуске, но при последующем выполнении кода  не происходит изменения картинки,  причем я точно знаю, что данные измененные загружены и обработаны,  предыдущие данные очищены - храню в просто массиве, буферы вершин, нормалей и индексов после передачи данных отбинжены как и рекомендуется - `gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);` 
Перед отрисовкой  поверхности с помощью `gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, ..... )`
пробовал дополнительно очищать буферы с помощью `gl.deleteBuffer`

Посоветуйте кто в теме....

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, те данные продолжают подгружаться из БД,поэтому и не происходит изменения. Там ничего очищать не надо: вы просто меняете координаты точек и выполняете перерисовку